# "Division by constant zero"? Microsoft Visual C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, multiplication

Why am I getting an error message of "**Error   1   Division by constant zero       25  17  ConsoleApplication3**"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Higher, Lower... What is the highest possible number that you're thinking of?");
            string b = Console.ReadLine(); 
            int f = int.Parse(b);//   F = THE MAX #
            Random computerguess = new Random();
            int computerGuess = computerguess.Next(f);
            Console.WriteLine(computerGuess);
            Console.WriteLine("if your number is higher than the number displaid above, then press the '1' key so I guess higher. if your number is lower press the '0' (down) as in telling the comp to go down/lower");
            string I = Console.ReadLine();            
            int G = int.Parse(I);
            int H = 1/2;

            if (G == 0)
            {
                computerGuess = computerGuess * H;                    
                Console.WriteLine(computerGuess);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Show me the error, there is no error in the source that you offer us. Make a scween-print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing an integer division:

```
int H = 1/2;
```

This will be zero always. Instead use a decimal:

```
decimal H = 0.5M;
```

and then cast your `computerGuess` back to int:

```
..
computerGuess = (int)(computerGuess * H);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
int H = 1/2;
```

sets H to 0: 0.5 rounded down to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get that error message when I try to compile your code.

The error message might be a bit misleading. This is line 25, that doesn't actally divide by zero:

```
int H = 1/2;
```

You are dividing integers, so the result will be zero. This calculation is done by the compiler, so the code generated is equivalent to:

```
int H = 0;
```

You probably get a warning because the result is most likely not the intended.

Answer (score 0):

About the line...

```
int H = 1/2;
```

You are triying to store the float value 0.5 inside a Integer var.